# getting a count based on multiples of three

Tags: c#, group-by

I have the following object values

```
UserId '1234'
Userid '1234'
Userid '1234'

UserId '986'
UserId '986'
```

What I want to achieve is a count of users that have multiples of three.
Above should produce a count of 1

In the below case the count should be 2

```
UserId '1234'
Userid '1234'
Userid '1234'

UserId '986'
UserId '986'
UserId '986'
```

So something along the lines of

```
var count = usersSatisfied.GroupBy(t => t.UserName).Count();
```

but where the username count satisfies a condition of three

Hope this makes sense

Thanks

Comment: To clarify: you want to obtain the number of groups (by user id) whose count = 0 (mod 3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
usersSatisfied
.GroupBy(c => c.UserName)
.Where(grp => grp.Count() % 3 == 0)
.Select(grp => grp.Key);
```

Comment: It should be `Where(grp => grp.Count() % 3 == 0)`